# how to display table using a flatlist in react native (with 2 columns, one for id and one for date)

Tags: fetch, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

```js
createTableFL(){
    var { isLoading, tableData } = this.state;
    return(
        <ScrollView style={{marginTop:10}} >
            <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
                <View style={styles.containerT}>
                    <FlatList
                    data={tableData}
                    style={{flex:1,marginVertical:20}}
                    keyExtractor={(x,i)=>i}
                    renderItem={({item,i}) =>
                    {
                        <View>
                            <Text>{item.inventory_id}</Text>
                            <Text>{item.created_on}</Text>
                        </View> 
                    }}
                    numColumns={1}
                    />

                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </ScrollView>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

set column number like this :`numColumns={2}`

Answer (score 1):

Please check `https://aboutreact.com/example-of-gridview-using-flatlist-in-react-native/` link for reference.

else you just change the number of columns of your table by assign value to `numColumns={number of columns you want}`.

Hope this works for you.